# QThread state when at start() call thread is still running, but after is already not

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread, qmutex

I have a GUI thread where I call `write(QString text)` method of another `MyQThread`.
`MyQthread` contains `QMutex mutex` and `QList<QString> list`. Here is the `write()` and `run()` methods of `MyQThread`:

```
void MyQThread::write(QString text)
{
     mutex.lock();
     list.append(text); //Point C
     mutex.unlock();
     start(); //Point D
}  

void MyQThread::run()
{
     mutex.lock();

     while(!list.isEmpty())
     {
         QString text = list.takeFirst();
         mutex.unlock();
         ...//do something
         mutex.lock(); //Point A
     }

     mutex.unlock(); //Point B
}
```

For example we are at the 'point A'. After this point we are checking the list and it is empty, so we are going to 'point B'. At this moment `write()` is called, mutex is still locked, so GUI thread is waiting before 'point C'.
Now we are at the 'point B', after this GUI thread is unlocked and start() ('Point D') is called.
Is it possible, that at 'point D' MyQThread is still running?
In this case calling of `start()` do nothing. And newly added item in the `list` will not be processed in `run()` until next call of the `write()`.
Additional information. In my case here is only one instance of MyQThread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@alexisdm thanks for the idea. What about this solution:

```
class MyQThread:
    public: QThread
{
    ...
    QList<QString> list;
    QMutex mutex;
    QWaitCondition listNotEmpty;
}

void MyQThread::write(QString text)
{
     QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
     list.append(text);
     listNotEmpty.wakeAll();
}  

void MyQThread::run()
{
     forever
     {
         mutex.lock();
         if(list.isEmpty())
             listNotEmpty.wait(&mutex);

         if(list.isEmpty())
         {
             mutex.unlock();
             continue;
         }
         QString text = list.takeFirst();
         mutex.unlock();
         ...//do something
     }
}
```

And what about the second parameter of `wait()` - `unsigned long time = ULONG_MAX`.
It seems that in my case it will not be error, when `write()` method is not called for a long time and `wait()` will return `false` in `run()` after `ULONG_MAX`. And in this case I need just to wait again...

And in documentation is written:

> The mutex will be returned to the same locked state.

Does it mean, that mutex will be always locked after `wait()` even if mutex was not locked before `wait()` or `wait()` returns false?

Comment: `ULONG_MAX` is a special value that isn't evaluated as a time, on Windows, for instance, it corresponds to the `INFINITE` value passed to `WaitForSingleObject` (see the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx)), so wait won't return `false` in that case. Since you can't unlock an unlocked mutex, and `wait()` does unlock the mutex before actually waiting, it should always be locked before `wait()`. And even if wait returns false, the mutex is returned in the locked state.

Comment: You should also edit your answer to make more clear that `listNotEmpty` is a `QWaitCondition`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Although the probability of having a race condition is low, I believe there's still a chance that QThread will still be sending signals and such. Use [QThread::wait](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#wait) before you call `start()` to be sure.

Edit: Agreed on the need to consider [QMutexLocker](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qmutexlocker.html#details). That code's going to get scary complicated pretty fast and you can't be sure that you'll remember to unlock with every exit point.

Edit2: Perhaps a [QReadWriteLock](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qreadwritelock.html) might be more interesting in your case?

Comment: I would like to lock only MyQThread, and avoid locking of GUI thread. In case of `QThread::wait()` GUI will be locked till MyQthread is finished.

Comment: My point is that the amount of time between Point B and the thread finishing should be a _very_ short amount of time. Using `QThread::wait()` in the GUI thread gives the main event loop that small amount of time required to handle any signals and slots connected to your thread finishing. It shouldn't lock for long.

Comment: @Funt Restarting the thread might still lock the GUI thread anyway, depending on system load. Can't you just keep the thread running but locked ? Since your problem is basically a "producer-consumer" problem, `QWaitCondition` might help (and the documentation has [an example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-waitconditions.html) ).

Comment: @alexisdm In my opinion, you just made the most sensible suggestion.

Comment: @alexisdm yes, you are right. But in this example thread is running till DataSize is processed. And in my case I need to use `start()` and `while(!list.isEmpty())` even with `QWaitCondition`. And that will cause the same problem :( Maybe I could just replace `while(!list.isEmpty())` with `forever` and call `start()` only once. That will solve my problem. But I am not sure whether that is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

QThread has the methods 'isRunning' and 'isFinished'. So you could query the thread state. And sure, your thread could still be running at 'Point D'.

But you really should stop here and do some reading.
https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong
and
http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html

And most certainly the Qt docs about the QMutexLocker.

Comment: QMutexLocker will lock GUI thread (before 'Point C') until `run()` is finished (right?). And I would like to append items to the list while `run()` is running.

Comment: Actually, you can't use only these states, because they might be set from the thread itself, so the thread might still be running when `isFinished()` returns false. You need to combine that state check with a call to `wait()` to be sure.

Comment: Small mistake: I meant "when isFinished() returns true".